# Webscrape to Pandas DF to txt

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium

Im trying to save web scrape via selenium to Pandas dataframe, which should either append new values and then remove duplicates, or add new values from the start.

I am struggling with the first step - adding data to the dataframe. Data scrape works, and I used to save data via file.write, which worked perfectly, but when Im trying to pass it to DF, only first value is added, (loop through links is working, and multiple values are extracted, but not written to df).

Please assist :(

Current script:

```
for link in links:
    try:
        sleep(randint(5,10))
        driver.get(link)
        myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "item" )))
        
#DATA
        #NAME DATA
        try:
            product = [driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'name').get_attribute('innerHTML')]
        except Exception:
            product = ["Other"]
        #BRAND DATA
        try:
            brand = [driver.find_element_by_xpath("// span[contains(text(),'Brand')]/following-sibling::p").get_attribute('innerHTML')]
        except Exception:
            brand = ["Other"]
            
    except:
        pass
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(product, brand)), columns=['Product', 'Brand'])
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('C:/product data DF.txt', sep='\t', mode='w', index=False)

driver.quit()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For each pass through the loop, you're creating `product` as a *new* list with one item.  The same for `brand`.

So when you create your DataFrame, `product` and `brand` contain only the data for the **last** link you processed in the loop.

Instead, you should create `product` and `brand` as empty lists before you start the loop, and `.append` to them on each iteration of the loop.